# Unable to inject Bean properties in Spring Bean BasicDataSource

Tags: apache-camel, jbossfuse

I'm trying to use in the BasicDataSource the username and password as derived from a Bean class:

```
<bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" id="myDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.teiid.jdbc.TeiidDriver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:myurl"/>
    <property name="username" value="${bean:quickstartConfiguration?method=getQueueUsername}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${bean:quickstartConfiguration?method=getQueuePassword}"/>
    <property name="maxIdle" value="1"/>
</bean>
```

In my project I have a Bean class named QuickStartConfiguration with methods getQueueUser and getQueuePassword.
Unfortunately, when the route gets instantiated, it seems that the username and password is not parsed:

```
 The username "quickstartConfiguration?method=getQueueUsername" and/or password and/or payload token could not be authenticated by security domain ldap-security.)
```

What is weird is that however using the log component, I'm able to retrieve the actual value from the Bean:

```
 <log id="async-queue-cred-log" message="----> Using username '${bean:quickstartConfiguration?method=getQueueUsername}' for the async queue"/>
```

Is there any limitation in the BasicDataSource class which prevents from evaluate the Bean expression?
Thanks!

Comment: Just to know it, I've got the right advice to make it working:
${quickstart.queue-username}

Comment: If you have the answer, can you post it as an actual answer for the sake of other people who have the same problem?